# Best practice for control flow charts

Tags: packages, graphics, diagrams

I wanted to plot a flow chart graph which looks similar to this diagram:

[image: flow chart]

that comes from [this source](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominanzrelation_%28Kontrollflussgraph%29).

1. Which package would be best for that?
2. I don't want to use pstricks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An example with [pgf/tikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) just for your inspiration.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[%
    ->,
    shorten >=2pt,
    >=stealth,
    node distance=1cm,
    noname/.style={%
      ellipse,
      minimum width=5em,
      minimum height=3em,
      draw
    }
  ]
    \node[noname] (1)                                             {1};
    \node[noname] (2) [below=of 1]                                {2};
    \node[noname] (4) [node distance=1cm and 3mm,below left=of 2] {4};
    \node[noname] (3) [left=of 4]                                 {3};
    \node[noname] (5) [below=of 4]                                {5};
    \node[noname] (6) [node distance=2cm,right=of 5]              {6};

    \path (1) edge                   node {} (2)
          (2) edge                   node {} (3)
          (2) edge                   node {} (4)
          (2) edge                   node {} (6)
          (3) edge                   node {} (5)
          (4) edge                   node {} (5)
          (5) edge [bend right=20pt] node {} (2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

More examples in the according [tikZ Example Gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/automata-and-petri-nets/).

---

[image]

Comment: The empty nodes on edges are useless. Why?

Comment: @Leo: I added them just for the case that the connections need some labels later. But you are right. For simple connections they can be dropped.

Comment: Is there a way to make the circles to ellipsis?

Comment: See my edits above.

Answer (score 11):

This doesn't need TeX. You can just use `graphviz` to draw such graph.
Of course, many LaTeX packages like `pstricks` and `tikz` can draw these graph, but I think `graphviz` is still easier to use.

It seems an example copied from [main page](http://www.graphviz.org/) of `graphviz` will be useful. With `graphviz` we don't have to tell computer where the nodes are, only edges are needed.

```
digraph finite_state_machine {
    rankdir=LR;
    size="8,5"
    node [shape = doublecircle]; LR_0 LR_3 LR_4 LR_8;
    node [shape = circle];
    LR_0 -> LR_2 [ label = "SS(B)" ];
    LR_0 -> LR_1 [ label = "SS(S)" ];
    LR_1 -> LR_3 [ label = "S($end)" ];
    LR_2 -> LR_6 [ label = "SS(b)" ];
    LR_2 -> LR_5 [ label = "SS(a)" ];
    LR_2 -> LR_4 [ label = "S(A)" ];
    LR_5 -> LR_7 [ label = "S(b)" ];
    LR_5 -> LR_5 [ label = "S(a)" ];
    LR_6 -> LR_6 [ label = "S(b)" ];
    LR_6 -> LR_5 [ label = "S(a)" ];
    LR_7 -> LR_8 [ label = "S(b)" ];
    LR_7 -> LR_5 [ label = "S(a)" ];
    LR_8 -> LR_6 [ label = "S(b)" ];
    LR_8 -> LR_5 [ label = "S(a)" ];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a complete example to make others comprehend how to include that in a LaTeX document?

Comment: `graphviz` is not a part of TeX. Just use `\includegraphics` to import the graph.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I discovered the [graphvizzz](http://code.google.com/p/graphvizzz/) package.

Comment: @Thorsten I have never use it but it should be useful. This [dot2tex](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/) can convert xdot output from Graphviz to a series of PSTricks or PGF/TikZ commands

Comment: You can convert the dot-file to a 'native' LaTeX tikZ image but running `dot2tex` on the dot-file. It will yield a .tex file containing the tikZ command you're after

Answer (score 2):

If you want to draw graph (graph theory) diagram, then PSTricks can do this easily.

See this [tutorial](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/joshi/joshi.pdf).

Comment: I think answers on this site should be self-contained. Please add an example from the tutorial.