# Generate System context diagram in TeX?

Tags: diagrams

Good afternoon,

Is there a way I can generate a system context diagram in LaTeX? - See below for example diagram:

[image: Example]

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9057/best-practice-for-control-flow-charts/9063#9063, that might help you get started. If you have more specific problems ("How do I influence the curvature of connecting lines?", "How can I get drop shadows behind nodes?"), feel free to add a new question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is an enthusiastic, **yes**! There are many options available, including

- tikZ (very popular on this site, you'll probably see a solution soon)
- PSTricks (example shown below)

The code below uses the `pst-node` package, see the documentation for details.

[image: control vehicle drive mk1]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,10)
 %\psgrid % useful during construction
 % draw the main nodes
 \cnodeput[shadow=true](5,5){control}{\begin{tabular}{c}Control\\Carpark\\(System)\end{tabular}}
  \rput(2,8){\rnode{vehicle}{\psshadowbox{Vehicle}}}
  \rput(8,2){\rnode{driver}{\psshadowbox{Driver}}}
  % connections from vehicle to control
  \nccurve[angleA=-90,angleB=180,linestyle=dashed,arrows=->]{vehicle}{control}
  \ncput*{Entry}
  \nccurve[angleA=-45,angleB=145,linestyle=dashed,arrows=->]{vehicle}{control}
  \ncput*{Arrival}
  \nccurve[angleA=0,angleB=125,linestyle=dashed,arrows=->]{vehicle}{control}
  \ncput*{Exit}
  % connections from drive to control
  \ncdiag[armA=2cm,armB=1cm,linearc=0.5,angleA=25,angleB=0,arrows=<->]{driver}{control}
  \ncput*{Paid-ticket}
  \nccurve[angleA=45,angleB=-15,arrows=<-]{driver}{control}
  \ncput*{Ticket}
  \nccurve[angleA=180,angleB=-90,arrows=->]{driver}{control}
  \ncput*{Issued-Ticket}
  \nccurve[angleA=135,angleB=-45,arrows=->,linestyle=dashed]{driver}{control}
  \ncput*{Request}
  % arrows
  \psnode(1,1){S}{}
  \psnode(1,3){N}{}
  \ncline[arrows=->,linestyle=dashed]{S}{N}
  \ncput*{Control Flow}
  \psnode(1,4){S1}{}
  \psnode(1,6){N1}{}
  \ncline[arrows=->]{S1}{N1}
  \ncput*{Data Flow}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

If you haven't used `PSTricks` before, there are a few things no note. Either compile the code with:

```
latex myfile.tex
dvips myfile.dvi
ps2pdf myfile.ps
```

or

```
xelatex myfile.tex
```

If you want to use `pdflatex`, then make your preamble look as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
....
```

and you can then run

```
pdflatex -shell-escape myfile.tex
```

**EDIT**

Here's another version that is slightly more pleasing than my original (imho); it uses `\ncarc` rather than `\nccurve`

[image: control vehicle drive mk2]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,10)
 %\psgrid % useful during construction
 % draw the main nodes
 \cnodeput[shadow=true](5,5){control}{\begin{tabular}{c}Control\\Carpark\\(System)\end{tabular}}
  \rput(2,8){\rnode{vehicle}{\psshadowbox{Vehicle}}}
  \rput(8,2){\rnode{driver}{\psshadowbox{Driver}}}
  % connections from vehicle to control
  \ncarc[arcangle=-45,linestyle=dashed,arrows=->]{vehicle}{control}
  \ncput*{Entry}
  \ncarc[linestyle=dashed,arrows=->]{vehicle}{control}
  \ncput*{Arrival}
  \ncarc[arcangle=45,linestyle=dashed,arrows=->]{vehicle}{control}
  \ncput*{Exit}
  % connections from drive to control
  \ncarc[ncurv=1,arcangle=-90,arrows=<->]{driver}{control}
  \ncput*{Paid-ticket}
  \ncarc[arcangle=-25,arrows=<->]{driver}{control}
  \ncput*{Payment}
  \ncarc[ncurv=0.75,arcangle=-60,arrows=<-]{driver}{control}
  \ncput*{Ticket}
  \ncarc[arcangle=45,arrows=->]{driver}{control}
  \ncput*{Issued-Ticket}
  \ncarc[arrows=->,linestyle=dashed]{driver}{control}
  \ncput*{Request}
  % arrows
  \psnode(1,1){S}{}
  \psnode(1,3){N}{}
  \ncline[arrows=->,linestyle=dashed]{S}{N}
  \ncput*{Control Flow}
  \psnode(1,4){S1}{}
  \psnode(1,6){N1}{}
  \ncline[arrows=->]{S1}{N1}
  \ncput*{Data Flow}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks (and apologies for not noticing the answers sooner!)

Answer (score 13):

A simple example using `TikZ` could be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm, inner sep=3mm, minimum width=1.5cm, >=stealth']
\node [draw, rectangle, drop shadow, fill=white] (V) at (0,0) {VEHICLE};
\node [draw, circle, drop shadow, fill=white, text width=2cm, align=center] (C) [below right=of V] {Control Carpark (System)};
\node [draw, rectangle, drop shadow, fill=white] (D) [below right=of C] {DRIVER};

\node (ctrl1) [above=of D] {};
\node (ctrl2) [above right=of C] {};
\node (ctrl3) [right=of C] {};
\node (ctrl4) [above right=of D] {};

\path [draw, ->, dashed] (V) edge node [fill=white] {Arrival} (C)
                         edge [bend left] node [fill=white] {Exit} (C)
                         edge [bend right] node [fill=white] {Entry} (C);
\path [draw, ->, dashed] (D) edge node [fill=white] {Request} (C);
\path [draw, ->] (D) edge [bend right] node [fill=white] {Issued-Ticked} (C)
                 edge [bend left] node [fill=white] {Payment} (C)
             (C) .. controls (ctrl1) and (ctrl3) .. node [fill=white] {Ticket} (D);
\path [draw, <->] (D) .. controls (ctrl4) and (ctrl2) .. node [fill=white] {Paid-Ticket} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The code can be tweaked to be more similar to the original figure, but I think the main ingredients are there:

1. nodes to create both the boxes and 'waypoints' for the paths
2. `positioning` library is loaded, so you can scale the figure more efficiently and do not have to specify explicit coordinates
3. `controls` in a path to have a custom curve for the arrows and avoid overlapping
4. `shadows` library for the drop shadows
5. and the white fill to avoid text overlapping with arrow lines.

The result is this:

[image]

Comment: Very elegant. The more I see `tikZ`, the more I think I may migrate to it.