# How can I draw a DAG?

Tags: technical-drawing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typesetting a directed, weighted graph with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37185/typesetting-a-directed-weighted-graph-with-tikz)

I would like to draw a DAG - [Directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at the packages `TikZ` and `pstricks`. You will find much information and examples in the web. For example: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples or http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

Comment: If you decided which package you prefer, and if you then have a problem in creating the drawing, you could edit your question and show to us what you have tried, so we could help you to improve that.

Comment: I'd go with the TikZ package and its `automata` and `positioning` libraries.`:)`

Comment: For a possible solution see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9057).

Comment: Also, you might consider using metapost.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I'm with trouble to print in pdf, I just can print it into DVI?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A solution with `tkz-graph` based on `TikZ`. You can used the styles from `TikZ` but you need to learn another syntax (very minimal) and you can use `TikZ`.

An advantage is that you can use `scale` without difficulty.

```
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{tkz-graph}  
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}%   
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{document}

    \tikzstyle{VertexStyle} = [shape            = ellipse,
                               minimum width    = 6ex,%
                               draw]

    \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}   = [->,>=stealth']      

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5] 
    \SetGraphUnit{2} 
    \Vertex{11}  \NO(11){5}   \WE(11){2} \SO(11){7} \EA(11){10}
                 \SOEA(11){9} \SOEA(10){3}\SOEA(9){8}
    \Edges(5,11,10) \Edges(3,8,9) \Edges(7,11,2)
    \Edges(11,9)    \Edges(3,10)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

The first example of your link gives

[image]

Comment: that is what some people like: that others do _all_ the work ...

Comment: @Herbert I read your comment as criticism of both Altermundus and Filipe... but I would like to stress that without the answer of Altermundus, I would not have known about tkz-graph and its potential for simplifications (and I am probably not the only one). Considering that Altermundus himself is the author of tkz-graph (unless I am mistaken), I would judge that his answer is a win-win-situation for him and Filipe.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I'm with trouble to print in pdf, I just can print it into DVI?

Comment: @FilipeFerminiano Use comments, not answers, please.