# Design block diagrams or flow charts in latex

Tags: flow-charts

What is the best way or latex tools for writing block diagrams/flow charts?
Is there any general pattern/template for that purpose?

Thanks for assist,
Tommy

Comment: There are so many questions about that on TeX-SX, if you search for them. An example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9057/best-practice-for-control-flow-charts

Comment: try https://ctan.org/pkg/schemabloc

Comment: See Section 3 here: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-1/tb121duck-tikz.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiLyNnRxej2AhVjSvEDHXLEC3IQFnoECAsQAg&usg=AOvVaw3JjsgxjzNRfpT5Sk7AkDjf